# How to implement a /dev/listener device in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I create a "listener" that would react like a `/dev/something` file, and all input redirect to it (like: `cat /text.txt > /dev/something`) will be read by the Ruby program?

In my eyes it looks like

```
dev = Device.new(/dev/something)
while dev.gets do
    ...
    ....
    .....
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is either [socket](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/UNIXSocket.html) or [named pipe](http://www.pauldix.net/2009/07/using-named-pipes-in-ruby-for-interprocess-communication.html). Check which one will be suitable for your application.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the easiest way to do this is like this:

```
ARGF.each_with_index do |line, index|
  puts "#{index}: #{line}"
end
```

And in your console you type `type stdin_read1.rb | stdin_read1.rb` where the first file can be any text-file.

This is the Windows syntax but I see you have no problem with the console part, I suppose the `cat` is the Linux equivalent.

You can just use `each`, I used `each_with_index` to demonstrate the text is not just piped.